# String comparison resulting in incorrect result

Tags: java

I have a path URL written in a file. I use the Scanner class to record that URL and output it to string variable "s". I then use the .equals() method to compare it and the path URL in my "gameDataFile" File object. The result is false, despite them being the same string as recorded in my console. What is happening here?

Path URL in file:

```
src\gameData\character_data.csv
```

Code snippet:

```
String s = in.next();                       // in is a java.util.Scanner object
System.out.println(gameDataFile.getPath()); // gameDataFile is a java.io.File object
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.equals(gameDataFile.getPath()));
```

Console output:

```
src\gameData\character_data.csv
src\gameData\character_data.csv
false
```

EDIT: as per request of @MTilsted, the following code snippet

```
String s = in.next();
System.out.println("'" + gameDataFile.getPath() + "'");
System.out.println("'" + s + "'");
System.out.println(s.equals(gameDataFile.getPath()));
```

Results in the console output:

```
'src\gameData\character_data.csv'
'
false
```

It seems to have replaced the URL with one single quotation mark

Comment: Try to change System.out.println(s); to System.out.println("'" + s + "'"); (And do the same for gameDataFile.getPath(). Sounds like one of them have a space

Comment: Changing "System.out.println(s)" to "System.out.println("'" + s + "'")" changed the corresponding output to just be one single quote mark. How did that happen and what does that mean?

Comment: There might be leading/trailing spaces that are difficult to see.

Comment: What does `s.compareTo(gameDataFile.getPath())` return? A return of `0` means that they are equivalent.

Comment: @JacobBlomquist it returns a 1

Comment: Was the file created with Notepad?  It may start with a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character.  Try printing `(int) s.chatAt(0)`.

Comment: @VGR
The output of that was 115 which is the ascii character for 's'. Everything seems alright in that regard.

Comment: The quotation mark output leads me to believe that `s` ends with a carriage return character, `'\r'`.  Try printing `s.endsWith("\r")`.

Comment: @VGR
Bingo, seems the String "s" gives us 1 more character than is shown. There seems to be a hidden "Carriage return" character (ascii code 13). I have never encountered this thing. Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Instead of using a Scanner, use the `readLine()` method of BufferedReader.  It will account for both `\n` and `\r\n` as newline sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
String s = in.next();                       // in is a java.util.Scanner object
System.out.println("'" + gameDataFile.getPath() + "'"); // gameDataFile is a java.io.File object
System.out.println("'" + s + "'");
System.out.println(s.equals(gameDataFile.getPath()));
```

Comment: The console outputs the following:  

'src\gameData\character_data.csv'  

'  

false

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VGR, the problem was that the String "s" contains an addition "Carriage return" character (ascii code 13).

Answer (score -1):

The utf8 file in windows has a BOM (byte order mark) at the start of the file by default. It is invisible, but it really exist. I think it cause two string different even if they look the same.

Comment: The asker checked for that.  No BOM found.

Answer (score -1):

add a backslash before the single quote